# visualvm showing 100% cpu for sleeping threads

Tags: profiler, java-threads, visualvm

I am learning the ropes on visualvm. I wrote the following small test program for playing with visualvm

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("hello");
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(true) {
                long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if((x-now)/1000 > 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It alternatively sleeps for 1sec and pegs one core for 2 seconds.
I ran it on intellij, which instruments it with some sort of agent

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java \
-javaagent:/home/sharath/softwares/idea-IU-232.9921.47/lib/idea_rt.jar=38335:/home/sharath/softwares/idea-IU-232.9921.47/bin \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/sharath/code/flinktest/target/classes sha.App
```

I then sampled the threads on visualVM. (Screenshot attached)[image: visualvm screenshot]

The part on the main thread makes sense - around 2/3 the time spent on cpu (94,618 ms) and rest of it sleeping (47,081ms). But what is bothering is the `java.io.BufferedReader.readline()`. Presumably it is the intellij java agent waiting for some user input, but it shows the thread at 100% on-cpu (141,700 ms)
I'm pretty sure thats wrong, because i would have observed 1 core usage on top. But the usage was ~50% as expected. Why does visualvm show the `readline()` function as on-cpu?

and similarly in the threads tab, [image: Threads tab of visual vm]
There are many threads like RMI threads which are shown as green (100% running) whereas i'm sure they will be sleeping most of the time. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Actually your code alternately sleeps 1sec and runs for 2sec because `long` is an integer type and `1000` an integer constant and integer division truncates, and that agrees with the 66+% visualvm reports. But I can't help with the threads created by IDEA.

Comment: wow you're right.. what a subtle point about the 2 sec runtime hehe :) I saw it in the profiler and i thought it was some timing issue, but now it makes sense .. but yeah the real issue is why visualvm shows inactive threads as "green" (running)